# Logout Another Device Laravel Socialte

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user AUTH VIA socialite API with google and twitter 
i want to Logout Another Device if someone login in another device

I want Only one Session for any User

I Used LARAVEL socialite Library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store the device identifier in users table which will identify the current device user is using to login.
2. Add the device identifier to session cookie/jwt whichever you are using as authentication mechanism when logging in a user.
3. Write a middleware that will check the session cookie/jwt device identifier with current device identifier stored in users table, if it matches then the user is using the same device otherwise they should login again from the new device.